# Add margin-top to textbox

Tags: html, css

So I'm building out a form and would like to make a major change - currently, I have the ntd-child call set on the second form field to always add margin-bottom: 40. I would like to change this.

I would like to be able to add margin-top: 40 each time the textbox classes are used below instead of adding margin-bottom: 40 each time to the second text field.

**Picture of the textbox class**:
[text-box class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y2J2.png)
[text-box 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6k3P.png)

---

**Picture of the second form field**:
[second form field class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UErUb.png)

```
#contact-content-wrapper .contact-content .wpcf7-form > p:nth-of-type(2), .generic_post_wrap .wpcf7-form > p:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-bottom: 40px; }
```

How would I be able to achieve this? Please let me know if you need me to be more clear.

Comment: Please add both form's html here. Having to look at the pictures and come back here isn't efficient. You might wanna look at How to post questions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling an inline-block to the label and removed the nth:child margin.

```
#contact-content-wrapper label[for="your-message"], .generic_post_wrap label[for="your-message"] {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```